# Send email to two addresses?

Tags: php, email

Is it possible to send the enquiry email to two addresses with the code below? If so how would I do it?

```
<?php if(isset($_GET['emailme']) && $_GET['emailme'] == 'true') { 
    // to and subject
    $to = "info@domain.com"; 
    $subject = "Product enquiry"; 

    // get these from query string
    $name_field = $_GET['name'];
    $hospital_field = $_GET['hospital']; 
    $department_field = $_GET['department'];
    $email_field = $_GET['email']; 
    $tel_field = $_GET['tel']; 

    // get wishlist
    $query = "SELECT w.*, p.product_name, q.quantity_name, o.product_code, o.description 
                FROM wishlistbasket w, products p, product_quantities q, product_options o 
                WHERE sesid = '$sesid' AND w.pid = p.id AND w.qid = q.id AND w.oid = o.id ORDER BY w.pid, w.qid, w.oid";
    $res = mysql_query($query);
    $wish_list = '';
    if($res){
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
            if ($row['qty'] == 1) {
                $row['qty'] = "Quote";
            } else if ($row['qty'] == 2) {
                $row['qty'] = "Sample";
            } else if ($row['qty'] == 3) {
                $row['qty'] = "Quote and Sample";
            }
            $wish_list .= $row['product_code'] . ' - ' . $row['product_name'] . ', ' . $row['quantity_name'] . ', ' . $row['qty'] . '' . $row['product_options'] . "
            \n";
        }
    }

    // build mail body
    $body = "Hello,\n\n
You have an enquiry from the website, please see the details below:\n\n 
Name: $name_field\n
Hospital/institution: $hospital_field\n
Department: $department_field\n 
E-Mail: $email_field\n 
Tel: $tel_field\n 
Wishlist:\n $wish_list"; 
    mail($to, $subject, $body); 
    echo "Thanks";} ?>
```

Comment: Just call the mail function two times, each time with a to address on it's own. (It's rather trivial so I add it as a comment).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`mail` accepts comma-separated list of recipeinets, as stated in [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php). So just set `$to` to something like

```
$to = "recipient1@domain.com,recipient2@domain.com";
```

Refer to [RFC2822](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2822.html) for more details on valid email address specifications.

Comment: This will allow both recipients to see each others email addresses. For privacy reasons I don't think this answers the question nicely.

Comment: @Treffynnon, are you sure it's not intended? OP said nothing about it.

Comment: No (hence no down vote), but it should be pointed out as a caveat for using this method.

Comment: The recipients are from the same company so that doesn't matter so much.

Comment: Bcc. Just saying. See RFC-822. (I can't believe I know the RFC number by heart!)

Answer (score 2):

### The simplest fix

```
...
// build mail body
    $body = "Hello,\n\n
You have an enquiry from the website, please see the details below:\n\n 
Name: $name_field\n
Hospital/institution: $hospital_field\n
Department: $department_field\n 
E-Mail: $email_field\n 
Tel: $tel_field\n 
Wishlist:\n $wish_list"; 
    mail($to, $subject, $body);
    mail($to2, $subject, $body);
    echo "Thanks";
...
```

### Comma separated `To:`

Whilst mail will allow you to send using a comma separated list of recipients this will not preserve their privacy. This is why I have used two calls to `mail()` so that they cannot see others email addresses.

### Using `BCC:`

Using a `BCC:` with `mail()` requires passing in the headers parameter. This is not recommended - see below.

### Suggestions

I would not recommend using the `mail()` function directly. Use [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) or [PHPMailer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/) as they provide more flexibility, safety and a better programming API.

Comment: I haven't downvoted your answer, but calling `mail` function twice is redundant - the same can be achieved by passing complex RFC2822-compliant `to` address, or by attaching additional headers.

Comment: @J0HN all of which is explained in my answer above BTW. Send to multiple `To:` does not achieve the same thing and attaching additional headers is not something that should be done with `mail()`. If you need to do this then use one the mailer projects I mention in my answer.

Comment: I would invite the down voters to actually read the answer before voting or improve their understanding on the subject.

Comment: You don't need a better API for this question, all you need is an additional header "Bcc" which PHP mail already accepts.

Comment: @EmanuelLandeholm for easily maintainable code I would never use the `additional_headers` parameter of `mail()` directly as you suggest. It is horrible and as soon as you start playing with it you __do__ need a better API.

Comment: So create your own class and hide the horribilities. PHP let's you do that.

Answer (score 2):

You could also do:

```
$to = "first@example.com, second@example.com";
mail($to, $subject, $body);
```

Hope it helps

Comment: This will allow both recipients to see each others email addresses. For privacy reasons I don't think this answers the question nicely.

Comment: Precisely. Which is why you would use additional header Bcc instead.

Answer (score 1):

PHP mail takes additional headers. Use Bcc: other@email.address

Comment: Your answer still exposes one person's e-mail address (the `to`) to the other (the `bcc`). In this case it's not important, but if you are going to suggest using BCC to prevent recipients from knowing each others' addresses...

Comment: (Good point!) Which is why your To: is always the same as Reply-To, ie. some account at the host, like info@the.site

Answer (score 1):

In order to send an email to multiple recipients, individually, with their email in the TO: field (not the BCC field), you will have to write a loop.

```
$addresses = ['user1@domain.com','user2@domain.com','user3@domain.com'];
foreach($addresses as $address){
   mail($address, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
```